# Facing an errors while executing a list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, list-comprehension

```
features_with_na=[features for features in df_main.columns if df_main[features].isna().sum()>1]
```

This list comprehension is supposed to give me all the columns with missing values. On execution, the following error comes up-

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-0878dbe5183a> in <module>()
----> 1 features_with_na=[features for features in df_main.columns if df_main[features].isna().sum()>1]

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the error message saying to change `df_main[features].isna().sum()>1` to `df_main[features].isna().any()`?

Comment: Works fine in python 3.7.6 and pandas 1.0.1. but why do list comprehension at all? Just do `df.columns[df.isna().sum() > 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.DataFrame.isna when called on a Pandas series returns an iterable of boolean values equal in length to the number of records in a dataframe

```
#calling isna on column returns series like [True, False, True, True...] equal to
#number of elements in df
df_features = [df_main[feature].isna() for feature in df_main.columns]

counts = [ftr[ftr == False].sum() in df_features]
```

I'd recommend using a solution from the comments, but this answer does return the list comprehension you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Do not use list comprehension when you do not have to:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=list('abc'))
df.iloc[3, 2] = np.nan
df.iloc[5, 1] = np.nan
df.iloc[6, 1] = np.nan
# just use boolean indexing
df.columns[df.isna().sum() > 1]

# Index(['b'], dtype='object')
```